# Can Java recognize variables placed in user input?

Tags: java, string, user-input

I'm new here. I'm wondering if Java can recognize variables input as a string.

Or, rather, would this work?

```
int Yn = 5;
System.out.println("please input the formula");
String x = keyboard.nextLine();
```

Will Java recognize it (if I input Yn) as letters or as a variable? If so, how could I 
make it recognize it as a variable? I ask as I am trying to create a program that will adapt to more than one formula for the Euler's method.

Comment: Java on its own will not recognize it as variable you will have to add that functionality on your own.

Comment: No. Variable names are only known at compile-time.

Comment: you want the input to be passed by a web application, a console or a swing/java fx application?

Comment: You need a map of "variable" names, and a parser.

Comment: Java is not an artificial intelligence. They're still projected at 20 years away. I believe that's been projected at 20 years away for my entire lifetime. You could implement a Domain Specific Language (DSL).

Answer (score 2):

No. Variable names are only known at compile-time. In order to do something like this, you will need to write your own basic parser.

Comment: Best way to use formula is expression with Array and its easy to render...hopes that you will precede with expression